# Google Analytics Java API Data Export

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to access information from google analytics, but every time it is giving me an exception:

```
Analytics API responded with an error message: Bad Request
```

Here is the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/ga-api-java-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/v2/csvprinter/AnalyticsCsvDemo.java) that I am using.

Any idea what's going on? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's using a very old version of the API that I don't think is supported anymore. [Here's a link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Analytics_API) to the current Java library for the Google APIs.